# Is Mysql UUID_SHORT() comparable to UUID()

Tags: mysql, sql, database, guid, uuid

A quick question or opinion if you will.

I need to generate some UUID's for a database table.

Auto incrementing keys won't cut it as I need the key to be unique across databases and systems also. UUID works fine however its output is too long for some of the systems that the rows will be exported to. UUID_SHORT() does the job fine and I have read MYSQL's conditions on guaranteeing its uniqueness.

ButI just want to double check that if I use UUID_SHORT() to generate UUID's for rows from time to time that they will indeed be unique in time and space as with UUID().

Cheers.

Comment: If you create compound primary key such as `PRIMARY KEY(id, server_id)` and then change the default value of `server_id` to any integer number on the machines / systems in question - you can achieve uniqueness without using GUIDs and still retain auto_increments.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. The tables need to be exported to csv's though routinely and then imported in other systems so the primary key should be one unique column as opposed to a compounded key from two columns. However that approach is very interesting and I will indeed look into it. Thanks. It is the unique key once the data leaves mysql and is in a flat file that is my primary concern really I guess.

Comment: This is why this approach allows for importing into other systems. Consider the case where you have `id=1, server_id=1` being imported into a system where `id=1` exists, but `server_id` is `2`. You won't get the PK clash, you'll know where from it was imported, your PK will be reasonably small, and you won't have to worry about plethora of things that come with GUIDs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`uuid_short()` produces a bitwise conglomeration of the server ID, a fairly static time component, and a sequentially increasing 24 bit integer. These bits are stuffed into an 8 byte integer. The time component is based on the server's boot time.

`uuid()` produces hex string that represents a 16 byte version1 UUID. Version 1 UUIDs are a bitwise conglomeration of the server ID, the current timestamp, a few bytes that come into play if you generation IDs at hyperspeed, and a few utility bits.

To answer your question: does `uuid_short` provide time and space uniqueness that rivals `uuid`? The answer is no. Case in point, the server ID in a `uuid_short` is only one byte. So if you have 256 or more servers, at least a few of them will have the same node id, which means you lose space uniqueness. For comparison, the server ID in version 1 UUID is 6 bytes long, effectively killing the chance of duplicates for all but the largest of corporate server farms :)

A better question is whether `uuid_short` is good enough. You could see ID collisions if you :

1. Generate more than 16 million IDS from the same server in little time. ***
2. Boot servers with the same server ID all at exactly the same time, and share data between them.
3. Fiddle with the system clock and then reboot your server.

The second issue seems unlikely for most people, but the first one is worth investigating before you commit to making `uuid_short` the basis of your keys.

*** Based on the mysql docs for `uuid_short`, it seems like you would see collisions if you generated more than 16 million IDs during the uptime of a single server. But that would be silly. The mysql docs go on to say that you are fine as long as you don't generate 16 million IDs per second. That implies that they must bump some of the bits in timestamp if you exhaust the 16 million sequential IDs. I have not tested this.

Comment: I think, this needs corrections:  First, mysql docs clearly state **per second**, I did not find **per uptime**.  Second: Server time does not need to be synchronized for collisions on the same server id, both servers only need to once hit the same second.  Third: Problems arise, if time on the server is not strictly monotonic raising.  So you will not get into a problem, if you warp the time forward (like after a reboot to correct time), only if you do it backwards!  (Sadly.  MySQL could use an internal monotonic counter which increments each second, but this seems not to be the case.)

Answer (score 4):

Your key question was, does `UUID_SHORT()` create values that are unique within time and space as with `UUID()`.  The short answer is yes, as long as you obey the special conditions MySQL requires.

The long answer is yes, but why would you want to use it?  The only apparent downsides to `UUID()` is its representation is less storage-efficient (generates a 36-character string rather than a 64-bit integer), and can't be used with statement-based replication.  But `UUID()` has the big upside of never having to think about the special conditions MySQL requires for `UUID_SHORT()`. If you're certain the conditions will never be a problem for you, and you're eager to save all of 224 bits per record, `UUID_SHORT()`is OK to use.  But if you have any concerns about the special conditions, then it's probably best to avoid it.

The degree of concern you would have about the special conditions depends a lot on your operational environment. The requirement to never set the system clock backwards between `mysqld` restarts is a big concern for me. Servers are often configured to have their clocks auto-synched with some other time source (e.g. `ntp` in unix, Time Service in Windows), and if this behavior isn't carried out to your expectations, then you may not be able to guarantee that condition is met consistently.

---